# Print one page with next 4 weeks of Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is there a way to print the next (coming) weeks from an Outlook Calendar on 1 page?

I can print a month, but it also prints days in the past. I want only future days.
I can print 4 pages of each 1 week, but I want 1 page.

I've downloaded and installed Outlook Calendar Printing Assistant, but there is no built-in template for the next X weeks. I'm trying to make one, but if anyone has any pointers, those are welcome too.